# ALAssetPropertyLocation not working on any iOS 4.0+ on 3gs iPhones but working perfectly on iPhone4

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocation, assetslibrary

I've got an app with location services ENABLED (from settings etc), and I'm reading all the photos from my device using ALAssetsLibrary.

It works perfectly on iPhone4 iOS 4.2.1, but the same code and the same assets DONT WORK on any 3gs any iOS (from 4.0 to 4.2.1).

The problem is that it retrieves always an invalid CLLocation on the 3gs.

Even on the same picture (copied across both devices) on the iPhone4 returns a valid CLLocation, on the 3gs it returns invalid!
The picture image itself it's valid on both devices, only the CLLocation is invalid. I dont have any crashes and the code doesnt step into any invalid blocks, it all works fine apart from the invalid CLLocation data.

Output of the *same asset* and *same code* and same *iOS version* (4.2.1):

**iPhone4**:
<+51.23816667, -0.57700000> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 19/02/2011 01:59:28 Greenwich Mean Time

**3gs**:
< nan, nan > +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 2011-02-19 01:20:35 +0000

(Note also the date on the invalid location is the current time)

Im getting the CLLocation like this:

```
 CLLocation* location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
 CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = [location coordinate];
 if ( !CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid(coord) ) return;
```

The ALAssetsLibrary code called in my viewcontroller DidLoad looks like this (totally standard):

```
ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

 void (^assetEnumerator)(struct ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
      if(result != NULL) 
      {
                [self myFunction:result withIndex:index];

      }
 };

 void (^assetGroupEnumerator)(struct ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) =  ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
      if(group != nil) 
      {
           numberOfAssets = [group numberOfAssets];
           [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:assetEnumerator];
      }
 };     

 [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                             usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                           failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
                                NSLog(@"Oh no!"); 
                           }];
```

One last thing, on the native photo app the pictures are shown in the correct location on the 3gs, so they must have that data somewhere, it just doesnt read it somehow!

I'm not entirely sure it's a device (3gs) problem, normally it never is...

Comment: Have you ever solved this problem? If yes please post an answer with the correct information because I am having the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not even seeing ALAssetPropertyLocation metadata on an iPhone 4 or iPad 3rd gen, and this is also with Location Services enabled (both in the app in question and for the Camera app). I take the photo, look at the metadata, and EXIF is there, but not much else.

Comment: Try posting a reduced example to bugreport.apple.com. They are usually helpful in a case like this.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 4.0 and higher, you can try using something like this to operate on the ALAsset and retrieve the location data (and more) for a photo asset that is retrieved either by enumerating or using `assetForURL`:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [asset defaultRepresentation];
NSDictionary *metadata = [representation metadata];
NSDictionary *gpsDict = [metadata objectForKey:@"{GPS}"];

NSNumber *latitudeNumber = [gpsDict objectForKey:@"Latitude"];
NSString *latitudeRef = [gpsDict objectForKey:@"LatitudeRef"];

NSNumber *longitudeNumber = [gpsDict objectForKey:@"Longitude"];
NSString *longitudeRef = [gpsDict objectForKey:@"LongitudeRef"];
```

The latitude and longitude Refs are directions that you will need to translate into positive (N, E) and negative (S, W). You can then use all of that information to build a simple CLLocation. If you need more, log or use the debugger to look at gpsDict (or metadata) and see which keys to use.

Keep in mind that the data is not always there (photos taken in airplane mode) so be sure to check the values.

Comment: This seems to not be working now in iOS 7, even when my Camera has Location Services enabled. A photo imported from the asset library does not seem to contain the "{GPS}" entry in its metadata dictionary. Anyone know why that might be happening?