# ALAssetPropertyLocation always invalid

Tags: iphone, alasset, geotagging, alassetslibrary

I am trying to get location information from photos and videos that an user selects from iPhone's library. I am using a custom image picker that uses ALAssetsLibrary to read the photos and videos.

I am trying to get the location information using `ALAssetPropertyLocation` like this:

```
CLLocation *location = [myAsset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
```

but `location` always comes up in the logs as

```
<nan, nan> +/- 0.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 9/21/11 1:37:56 PM Central European Summer Time
```

I've tried looking at `myAsset.defaultRepresentation.metadata` property and GPS location **IS** there but only for photos. For videos `myAsset.defaultRepresentation.metadata` is `nil`.

Any help would be great appreciated!

**UPDATE**

It looks like this guy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5050334/alassetpropertylocation-not-working-on-any-ios-4-0-on-3gs-iphones-but-working-pe) had a similar problem. But it only happened for him on a 3GS while having no problems on the iPhone 4. I am currently testing on an iPhone 4 and still getting the invalid location information.

Comment: Not really no :( In the end I haven't needed it anymore in the project I was working on and I haven't looked for a solution anymore. If you have any suggestions it would be great though.

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9581515/alassetpropertylocation-returning-nil